# How can I change the mac address on a Linux 3.3.8 device without macchanger?

Tags: mac-address

I'm trying to permanently modify my  MAC address on a device running Linux 3.3.8 I cannot get macchanger to install either.

When I try it with

```
ifconfig eth0 hw ether
```

I get

```
ifconfig: SIOCSIFHWADDR: Device or resource busy
```

I have ssh'd into the device. The device is on wifi and lan. I've connected through wifi and trying to change the lan's mac address. I've tried

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig etho hw NEW_MAC
get the error: ifconfig: SIOCSIFHWADDR: Device or resource busy
ifconfig eth0 up
```

ifconfig shows the mac address was updated. However the GUI elements still show the old mac address. Also, the changes are lost after restart.

Comment: Are you sure the device *isn't* busy? Is the device down?

Answer (score 0):

The device must first be stopped:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
```

Then you need to apply the changes:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

After that, start the device:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Comment: This did not work either :( I've added more information to my post.